# Where can I find the documentation?

Tags: documentation

I know, this is a stupid question, but can somebody tell my wehre I can find the documentation of ubuntu 13.04. I have not installed ubuntu yet, but I booted it from a CD.
I only want to use ubuntu.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know exactly what documentation are you looking for. Could you be more specific? Do you want to *develop* Ubuntu, *use* it, *repair* it..

Comment: You may want to start with the Ubuntu manual [Download here](http://ubuntu-manual.org/downloads).

Comment: Did you click on the Gear icon on the top right corner and select "Ubuntu Help"? Is this what you mean by documentation?

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start is the [Ubuntu 13.04 Release Notes wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes). Ubuntu.com also maintains similar Ubuntu Documentation wikis for frequently searched for topics such as proprietary drivers for graphics cards, hardware compatibility and many Community wikis.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Official Ubuntu Documentation Here → https://help.ubuntu.com/

Hope this helps... Good Luck!